# tomcat: force logback config to come from system path, NOT from inside war?

Tags: tomcat, logback

So I have a WAR. Let's call it HelloWorld.WAR. It contains a logback.xml that gets included into the war.

The system has a server-specific logback.xml. It's included via tomcat's setenv.sh. Let's call it /etc/logback.xml to avoid confusion.

When I start tomcat, it starts the application using /etc/logback.xml, then quickly switches to war/logback.xml.

I understand why this is. The logback.xml used is the last one found. So how can I make /etc/logback.xml the last one found?

Answer (score 0):

In your logback configuration use the debug switch to see what happens:

```
<configuration debug="true" ...
```

I assume your war file includes the logback libraries, just remove them (as Tomcat already has them when I understand your setting) and everything should work. When you use the debug switch, logback will complain that it found more than 2 instances on the classpath.

Much more is possible, take a look here: [Logging separation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html)